# C++ unique_ptr not calling the destructor

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a `vector` of `unique_ptr`s that point to a class called state. When I call `pop_back()` with the vector, the unique pointer is removed from memory (I think), but the state object that it pointed to never gets deleted. Either that or the unique pointer somehow doesn't call the destructor when deleting the object it points to? All I know is that my destructor doesn't get called when my unique pointer is removed from the vector.

This is the vector:

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<State> > mStates;
```

I tried:

```
mStates.pop_back();
```

That removes the unique pointer, and I thought the unique pointer would delete the state for me and call the state's destructor, but that didn't happen. BTW I add elements by using:

```
 mStates.push_back();
```

Comment: Please show some code that demonstrates your problem. You're surely misusing something, but we can't guess what without seeing the code. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm afraid [I can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/edTMSi).

Comment: can't reproduce: http://ideone.com/uMRUR2

Comment: how exactly are you determining that it does not work? sometimes OS do not free directly.

Comment: @syam Well ssome of the states are inherited form the base State class. I have PlayState and MenuState. Do inherited objects have virtual destructors?

Comment: @SusanYanders Ah, this may be the cause. Your base State class *must* have a virtual destructor (then your derived classes will automatically get a virtual destructor too, even if you don't manually specify it) otherwise you can't delete an object of a derived class through a base class pointer.

Comment: Any *decent compiler* should warn about a class with virtual methods but no virtual destructor.

Comment: @Walter I have VS 2012 which is pretty good

Comment: In my case, the `unique_ptr` was already `nullptr`!

Answer (score 16):

I fixed it. My problem was that I needed to have a virtual destructor. I didn't even consider that a virtual destructor could exist. It works now.

Comment: You should investigate your compiler options, g++ for sure can warn you about things like this.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Im starting to think VS2012 warned me at some point. Im just to lazy to look at the warnings

Comment: @SusanYanders, make the habit of getting rid of all warnings, even the ones about things you are doing for a reason (even if you have to disable a particular warning for a method or file). It will make tracking down errors like this, which can take up a significant amount of time and cause no end of frustration. Even better is to run something like lint which will pick up even subtler errors. Also if you didn't know about virtual destructors, you should read Effective C++ by Scott Mayer, it has lots of got-yas that you should know about.

Comment: Just encountered this with GCC 4.9.2 (2014-12-24) - no warnings about a missing virtual destructor in a base class with non-pure virtual methods.  I was assuming it was implicit but no, you have to declare a virtual destructor explicitly!

Comment: Closely related:std::unique_ptr::release() will not delete, use std::unique_ptr::reset() instead.

Comment: In C there is only a very low chance that a warning is actually not an error in disguise (apart from unused variable warning)